# If a service process dies in the middle of servicing a request, how does the client avoid waiting forever?

Tags: ros, roscpp, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It appears that if a service's process dies in the middle of handling a request, the service call on the client side will hang forever.

Is there any way around this besides putting the service call in its own thread and killing the thread after a timeout?

see: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/2913

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44078/if-a-service-process-dies-in-the-middle-of-servicing-a-request,-how-does-the-client-avoid-waiting-forever?/) by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2743 on 2012-09-18

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-09-18**:
How long did you wait? I think the sockets should die at some point, maybe after 2 minutes or so. Does the service client not throw an exception in that case? (I believe in roslisp, it does :))

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-09-19**:
Wow. I just tested your code and it really seems like the service call blocks forever...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

<del>Based on the client code attached in the ticket, I added the line:</del>

<del>if(!client.waitForExistence(ros::Duration(5.0))) continue;
before the service call (line 21). This allows the client to carry on and make service calls once the server comes up again.</del>

Retried the code again after Lorenz's comment. It seems this worked only when the server was killed at specific points in time (just before the service call I presume). Though I still don't understand why it worked previously when the "Failed to call service" line wasn't printed.

---

Originally posted by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) with karma: 2268 on 2012-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-09-18**:
I don't think that solves the problem of blocking service calls in the client that never return because the server went down.

**Comment by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) on 2012-09-19**:
It is true that particular service call (when server dies) does not return (I do not get the message "Failed to call service add_two_ints"). But the client does continue to run its next loop until waitForExistence and until the server comes up again. ie the client does not hang

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-09-19**:
The client actually cannot continue with its loop since the service call is blocking. I still don't see how waitForExistence could help if the service call just does not return, which is apparently the case.